# Link to full size image or attachment page in photo theme

Tags: images, attachments, media

My site is using WooThemes [Statua theme](http://www.woothemes.com/2011/06/statua/). I'm trying to get my resized slider images to link to their respective full size images (or attachment pages).

I asked a similar question on the WooThemes [support](http://forum.woothemes.com/topic.php?id=49784) [forums](http://forum.woothemes.com/topic.php?id=49812) (members login required) and the code they provided links the images to the resized 960px Large image size instead of the Full size images.

Here's [an example page](http://bit.ly/o9rkAC) on my site, using the single.php template, and its [code](http://pastebin.com/U0q1RPTe).

How can I get the slider images to link to the full size originals or attachment pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(  $post->ID ), "full" );

echo '<a href="' . $image[0] . '">Link to Full Size</a>';
```

Comment: For the large image to link to the full image, on what line should I add your $image href to the code: http://pastebin.com/U0q1RPTe

Comment: Around the IMG tag on lin3 43. It looks as though you've already done this.

Comment: I have the first line, starting with $image, on line 16 and the second line, starting with echo, on line 43. Unfortunately this still links to the resized Large image. Anyway to link this to the original, Full sized image?

Comment: Hmm, not sure, but you could just add a new image size like this: <pre>add_image_size('fullsize', 9999, 9999, false);</pre> then just link to the "fullsize" one.

Comment: I made some progress. I was able to add this link, and replace the current image links with it. However, this results in each link pointing to the same image. How can these link to their respective full size image?

Comment: Show the piece of code that displays the images. You need to make sure that the image call is in the loop, and not outside of it.

Comment: I received a reply from the WooThemes team that solved the issue. Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/fifRWWPP

Answer (score 0):

You have got a `$photo_size` variable in your linked code. Change it according to sizes listed in the Codex (from `large` to `full`). Furthermore, you should point Woo at [this](http://www.google.de/search?q=timthumb+exploit&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#pq=timthumb%20exploit&hl=de&sugexp=gsihc&cp=17&gs_id=y&xhr=t&q=timthumb+security&pf=p&sclient=psy&client=firefox-a&hs=oEc&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3Aofficial&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=timthumb+security&aq=0L&aqi=g-L1&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=d95124e4aea0a0bb&biw=1280&bih=841), as they are using timthumb in the theme.

Comment: Changing line 8 of the code from "large" to "full" has no effect http://pastebin.com/U0q1RPTe

Comment: @Ryan Then change `$width_setting` and `$height_setting`.

Comment: I changed both of these variables and there's no difference - the slider images still link to the resized photos. Any way to link to the original, full size photos?

Comment: This: `$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att_id, $photo_size, true);` is where the size of the linked image comes from. If it's not that, then you linked/pasted the wrong code.

Comment: I spent some more time on this and discovered when I edit the param "large" to "full" and the width/height_settings it only affects the initial display image, not the linked image. I think the `href="'. $src[0] .'"` needs to be edited, I'm just not sure to what. It seems as if the display image and the linked image both use the same paramater - is there a way to separate them? I appreciate your help.

Comment: write `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($src); echo '</pre>';` to dump the array that comes from `$src`. Additionally you can look up my asked Qs. There are some "How to" Qs that are there to explain such stuff.